# Python - How to use a GridSearchCV variable as a string

Tags: python, function, joblib, gridsearchcv

I have a variable called `model_LR`, it stores **GridSearchCV** parameters that should be passed as an argument in a function called `print_result` to dump the model and save it using **joblib** as follows:

```
def print_results(model):
    joblib.dump(model.best_estimator_, './data/{}.pkl'.format(model))
```

```
model_LR = GridSearchCV(lr, parameters, cv=5)
model_LR.fit(X_train, y_train)

print_results(model_LR)
```

No file is created while it returns 'OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument' apparently as it returns the value the argument carries not the argument name.

How can I use the argument name as a string, in this case, and assign it as a file_name.pkl?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: I don't understand what you try to do with `model` - it is not string and it doesn't have `name` (or any string values which you could use as `name`) and using `'{}'.format(model)` can be totally useless. Maybe first see what you get with `print( '{}'.format(model) )` or simply `print( model )` and you should see something like `<class ... >`. What `name` do you expect to get from model?

Comment: you should set name manually `print_results(model_LR, "string_with_name")` because you can't get name `model_LR` as string. It doesn't send it when you send variable to function - as it doesn't send name when you assign to other varaible - `x = model_LR`. And you want to have name as string then you should keep it in dictionary. `all_models = { "model_LR": GridSearchCV(lr, parameters, cv=5)}` and uses srting to acccess it `all_models["model_LR"]`

Comment: Thank you @furas for the explanation and I will consider your notes to improve the question readability.